# Images resize in one container but not another

Tags: javascript, android, css, react-native, expo

[ScreenShot of code and Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02vXZ.jpg)

I've been banging my head against the wall for a day on why this singular image won't be resized. I've gone through the docs multiple times and you can see from my commented-out styles how many different options I've gone through.

This issue is a great annoyance due to the fact that I've already resized similar images inside the app and yet for this item, it will not change the dimensions of the banner image under trending.

Ive tried using the image background, using a regular image with a basic container and resizemode, Ive tried upscaling the image from a smaller one. Ive tried every method in the documentation. Im thoroughly exhausted.

Comment: The image did not properly Crop so please view this one https://imgur.com/MBovehT

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.